# Write specific property of nested object to CSV

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm writing a CSV file based on an object which has another object nested in it.  I only want to write a specific property of that nested object, not all properties.

In the below example, my desired outcome would be to only write the network name of the user object to the CSV file, not the network name and operator ID.  However, as written, it will output both.  I could write a custom Definition map just for this scenario, but I'm wondering if I can indicate a specific property to use.

```
public sealed class InventoryDefinitionMap : CsvClassMap<InventoryItem>
{
    public InventoryDefinitionMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.inventoryId).Name("Inventory Id");
        Map(m => m.serialNumber).Name("Serial Number");
        References<UserDefinitionMap>(m => m.AssignedUser);
    }    
}

public sealed class UserDefinitionMap : CsvClassMap<User>
{
    public UserDefinitionMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.operatorId).Name("ID");
        Map(m => m.networkName).Name("Network Name");
    }
}

void WriteCSVFile(List<InventoryItem> Items)
    {
        using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(fileLoc))
        using(var Csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            Csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<InventoryItemDefinitionMap>();
            Csv.WriteHeader<InventoryItem>();

            foreach (Item I in Items)
            {
                Csv.WriteRecord(I);
            }
        }
    }
```